# MySQL Update with select

Tags: php, mysqli

I have a table with articles(articles) that have their contents to be updated by a team accessing them through the Internet(PHP) and assigning them automatically the articles to worked upon, based on the article status and id.
We have the id of the article(artid), its content(artcont) and its update status(artstat): Y(yes)/N(no)/B(blocked).

When one member of the team wants to work on updating articles, I want to automatically select for him the article that has its artstat "no" and the lowest articleid, setting at the same time artstat as "blocked" (to prevent it being edited at the same time by other team members).I want at the same time to return the artid that it's being edited.

For the moment, I have in PHP a select query followed immediately by an update one:

```
....(credentials for connecting to database)... 
$conn = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
$sql=SELECT * from articles where artstat='N' order by artid asc LIMIT 1;
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
if (mysqli_num_rows($result) == 1) {
// output data
$row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
echo "id: " . $row["artid"]. "<br>";
$upd = "UPDATE articles SET artstat='B' where artid=" .$row["artid"];
mysqli_query($conn, $upd);
}
else {
echo "0 results";
}
```

Now, my question is: is it possible that a second team member (on another opened connection) who wants to work on an article makes his request exactly between the execution of the select and update statements, he will get the same article to work with (artstat is not 'B' yet), isn't it?

How to avoid this?

Thank you.

Comment: `$sql=SELECT * from articles where artstat='N' order by artid asc LIMIT 1;` that's an outright parse error right there and/or even an undefined constant SELECT notice.

Comment: Yes, you have a potential _race condition_ there. The way around that are _transactions_.

Comment: I am thinking about stored procedures. If a stored procedure is called a second time by another teamworker, he will have to wait for the first call to be completed first? Or the server will try to execute them both as and when a call is made?

Answer (score 0):

In Mysql ,   there are two type of locking to avoid such situation  in **innodb** engine

- table level locking
- row level locking

  You will need row level locking  for this

You can read more about this from the below stack over flow post.

https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/15854/innodb-row-locking-how-to-implement

Comment: Thank you. Yes, I have thought about that. from what I understand, the locking is for update / delete, so I cannot lock the record to be read. I will read the article you point me up to, maybe I'll find a solution. Thanks again

Comment: A SELECT ..... FOR UPDATE has an "intention exclusive" (IX) record lock. A second transaction on the same record, using an select... for update statement is compatible. see link: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/innodb-lock-modes.html. So I cannot get a read lock on it.